# Dell laptop's screen goes to screen saver after a very short time

Tags: dell-inspiron

Not sure why, but recently my Dell laptop (Inspiron 1720) screen goes black after a very short time, e.g. if I am watching a video, the screen goes all black, I have to move the mouse cursor to get it back.

What could be the issue?

Comment: What is "a very short time"? Have you confirmed that this "short time" matches the power settings?

Comment: unbelievable.. I didn't think anybody could ask such a simple question

Answer (score 4):

Just turn off your screen saver or set the time to 3 hours or something longer than what it is currently set at.

Answer (score 3):

Look into your Power Options on the Screen Saver tab of Display Properties. Your selected power scheme is probably Portable/Laptop with default 'off' settings of 15 min when plugged in or 5 min when on battery power. Set values that satisfy you and (optionally) save it to a named power scheme. If it ever gets reset somehow, you'll be able to quickly recover.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to this! The screensaver showing up after a small period of time was driving me crazy as well! I have a Dell Inspiron 11 but the instructions are universal. So I thought it had to do with the power-saving options, so I completely turned it all off and it was still happening! Turns out it has nothing to do with it. Instead, right-click and go to "Personlize". Go to lock screen and scroll down and click on "Screen-saver Settings". It'll show you your screensaver and underneath it says "Wait x minutes". Mine was set to 1 MINUTE lol. Change to your ideal time and Voila! No more annoying screensaver. Hope this helps :)

Credit goes to YouTuber TRUEMILLER and his video called "Enable & Disable The Windows 10 Screensaver In 3 Seconds Flat"

Answer (score 0):

Right click on desktop (not on icon) → properties → screen saver.
Adjust time or switch off Screen Saver.

Then go to power options in this window (below) and adjust turning off monitor and hard drives. Remember to adjust power schemas for 'battery' and for 'ac plugged' :)

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, some Dell notebooks now have proximity sensor which locks the screen when you are not sitting in front of it.
This is managed by Dell Optimizer -> Proximity Sensor, completely independent from Windows screen saver settings.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had this problem on a new Latitude 5520 at work.  It was driving me bonkers.  Turned off the Proximity Sensor and BOOM, no more fade to black!